# TailwindCSS not working with Vite + React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

I am initializing TailWindCSS using https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app on a Vite + React + JavaScript project but cant get it to work, It seems like postcss and autoprefixer is not getting installed, when I try to install manually it gives the following error

```
warning Pattern ["postcss@^8.4.20"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "C:\\Users\\NUR\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Cache\\v6\\npm-postcss-8.4.20-64c52f509644cecad8567e949f4081d98349dc56-integrity\\node_modules\\postcss" as pattern ["postcss@^8.4.18","postcss@^8.4.20"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > tailwindcss@3.2.4" has unmet peer dependency "postcss@^8.0.9".
```

Comment: Perhaps try use [https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite) as a reference instead of the guide for CRA.

Comment: @JohnLi I have tried using the vite guide , it still doesn't work and gives the same issue

Comment: Can you show you package.json and tailwind.config.cjs ?

Comment: I have copied the TailWind config exactly from the guide

Comment: I just tried and only one thing went wrong, there was no postcss.config.cjs
Did you have it when you tried npx tailwindcss init -p ?

Comment: No , same for me , postcss isn't getting installed, and the config is also not generated on npx init

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I followed the doc to install tailwind with Vite and React and it didn't work too.

Don't install packages manually, use the `npx tailwindcss init -p`  but create manually the file `postcss.config.cjs` with :

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {}
  }
};
```

Don't forget the rest of the guide and it will work

Comment: In a comment, wrongly posted as [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76051569/5211833) here, mentions "in changing the default export to a module export, at least in my case, breaks the entire app."

Answer (score 17):

I followed the documentation to install tailwind with Vite and React and it didn't worked too. then i add these changes in vite.config.js and it worked.

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import tailwindcss from "tailwindcss";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  css: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [tailwindcss()],
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: and if you want to keep your postcss.config.js, you can move `tailwindcss()` from the vite config file to your separate postcss config file - for me, I had to place it before the other plugins that I am using.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the doc to install tailwind with Vite and React and it didn't work too and I was also creating my postCSS config file manually too which was wrong.

All I needed to do was use the `npx tailwindcss init -p` and it created both my tailwind config file and postcss config file for me automatically and solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

when you install react with vite@latest your autoprefixer node module is not install with node packages. so you need to generate first postcss.config.js using *npm install -D* autoprefixer and requred node module to run command   *npm install -D autoprefixer*

in short :-

1. need to install required postcss.config file :  npm install -D autoprefixer
2. install required node module : cmd  npm install -D autoprefixer